# Show element based on service variable (set by another component)

Tags: angular, angular7

I've got an application where I'm trying to show or hide an element based on a public variable in a service. This variable is instantiated like `show: boolean = false;` but is then set from child components.

My problem is that `show` never seems to update its value.

In doing various debugs, i found that `show` is set to whatever it's initial value is, but once the view initialization finishes, my inspector shows that `show` is undefined, although this may not be related to my issue.

***So how can I show a parent element from a child component?***

Code below:

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="appService.show"> Loading </div>
<div *ngIf="!appService.show"> Content </div>
```

**app.component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**app.service**

```
export class AppService {

    public show: boolean = false;

    showLoader() {
        this.show = true;
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.show = false;
    }
}
```

**child.component**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

// This is just an example, I've got the showLoader() method firing after a subscription completes.
    ngOnInit(){
        this.appService.showLoader();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to create an observable to manage the loading state. I prefer to use a `BehaviorSubject` because it remembers the last value it emitted. You can have multiple components subscribe to the loading service. (more on behavior subjects [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html)).

Here is a link to a stackblitz where I have implemented a simple version of this loader service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loading-service-subscribe

EDIT: I added the code for the `child.component` to the answer. I had it in the stackblitz, but forgot to add it here.

Key notes:

`loading.service.ts` has a `BehaviorSubject` that manages whether or not the app is loading data. It returns itself `.asObservable()` so no child components can call `.next()` on it.

```
export class LoadingService { 

  private _isLoading$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  get isLoading$(): Observable<boolean> { 
     return this._isLoading$.asObservable();
  }

   // see the rest of the code in the stackblitz 
}
```

Once that is wired up, inject it into the component.

`app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    // by making it public, you can subscribe in the template
    constructor(public loadingService: LoadingService) { }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="loadingService.isLoading$ | async" [ngIfElse]="loaded">
  Loading  
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loaded>
  Content has loaded
</ng-template>

<!-- see child.component -->
<child></child>
```

the child.component can then control the loading indicator by using the `loading.service`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <h1>Child Component</h1>
    <button (click)="toggleLoading()">Change Loading</button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(public loadingService: LoadingService) { }

  // simulates a 3 second load time for fetching data
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingService.startLoading();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadingService.stopLoading();
    }, 3000);
  }

  // simple method to simulate user action that loads some new data
  toggleLoading(): void {
    this.loadingService.toggleLoading();
  }
}
```

check out this resource for info on the `ng-template`: https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-else-then

and this one for the `async` pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: So I think this is the correct approach, however when I implemented your suggestions, I got the "Loading" template to show, but it never reaches the loaded state and constantly displays the "Loading" template.  In my index.html view, I display a static title using interpolation so there should be some content displayed.

Thinking on this, I should just be able to subscribe to the get isLoading$() method and then use the success output to determine that the loading is complete, correct?

Comment: I was actually able to answer my own question.  I missed the code to actually turn it on/off going into my child components.  Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working. Sorry I didn't include all the code in my answer that is in my stackblitz code.

Answer (score 1):

Make the show field as observable.

**app.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

  public show$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  constructor() { }

  showLoader() {
    this.show$.next(true);
  }

  hideLoader() {
    this.show$.next(false);
  }
}
```

And subscribe wherever you need to listen it.